# Should you use non admin account for daily browsing even if you're the only user of the computer?

Tags: windows-10, security, administrator

Title says it all. I've asked the same question on a poll on reddit and generally most people just use an admin account with uac.

I'm of course referring to the recommendation to keep a admin account and a standard account and to use the standard account for daily browsing.

When you look up this question, all the articles say to use two accounts but doesn't uac display a prompt when a program needs admin rights in a administrator account? Are there any permissions given to admin users that don't ask for uac (even if you keep uac on default or high)? Which a malware or drive by download could exploit? and for regular home users who know to not click on weird websites, what is recommended?

Thanks in advance. Windows 10 btw

Comment: Best practice is to use a normal user account and create a second one that's a part of the `Administrators` group _(do not enable the default `Administrator` account for this, as it's not secure to have the default Admin account enabled)_, secured with a complex passphrase, using the latter to approve Admin actions _(this is the default environment of all non-single-user *nix-based distros via `sudo`)_; however, most Windows users disregard this recommended configuration.

Comment: @JW0914 i guess it's probably because they don't want to worry too much bout security and think that since they know to avoid dangerous websites by common sense and ublock and keep thier stuff up to date. (me lol) i would probably use two accounts if i was working for a organization or something. but as a home user i guess im safe if i follow internet safety. Also can you define best practice? If it is very important, wouldnt windows do it by default?

Comment: Per [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts#restrict-and-protect-local-accounts-with-administrative-rights), "_The simplest approach is to sign in to your computer with a standard user account, instead of using the Administrator account for tasks... When you want to perform an administrative task... you don't have to switch to an Administrator account [and] can use User Account Control (UAC) to prompt you for permission or an administrator password before performing the task._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are logged in from an administrator account and UAC is enabled,
most of the programs are executed with the permission of a standard user.
The degree of protection varies according to the UAC level that you
choose.

The UAC prompt is not an absolute protection, as hackers are pretty
good about convincing you to press "Yes".
Meaning that the protection is only as good as your vigilance and
attention.

As standard account, no one can trick you into running a program with
elevation. In addition, many hacks that use vulnerabilities to elevate
a program won't work when the current user is on a standard account.

In short, if you are not an experienced Windows user, working under
a standard account is safer.

Comment: You said by using a standard account, no one can trick you into running a program with elevation. How is that possible? Using a standard account, you can still just type in the password and give access, when you know well how many scams work and if you stick to mainstream sites, are there any other ways you can get infected? Also can't most of the malware infested websites and files be avoided by common sense on what links to click and ublock? Thanks for your time btw

Comment: I've been using windows for many years so i guess ill just keep using a admin account. Thanks again.

Comment: Clicking Yes by lack of attention is not the same as typing in a password. It will also require the hacker to know the name of the Admin account (this is why the built-in Administrator account is disabled by default).

Comment: I doubt lack of attention is an issue. I know that clicking yes on the prompt means giving admin elevation to the program. Thanks again again.

Comment: Using a standard account is not necessarily more secure than UAC. There are vulnerabilities found all the time in modules that themselves *do* have admin rights on a machine but are accessible to standard users. Privilege escalation is a very real security problem for all types of users and while using a standard account might be better 99.99% of the time it is by no means infallible. Security is an ongoing process. Standard users are more useful in a network where you need to segregate users and limit the damage they can do or what they can access.

Comment: @Mokubai huh interesting. Well what do you recommend?

Comment: @Mokubai This has been making me think for a long time: do i just use an admin cuz i know my stuff and how to avoid dangerous websites and scams. or do i just use the double account instead. Been puzzling me for a while now lol.

Comment: Basically I see it as a question of self-confidence. For an experienced user that often installs applications or does other admin stuff, a standard account is a nuisance. For a less-active user, a standard account gives more confidence.

Comment: i see ill just use my admin one for now. I don't really do much admin stuff but i know what stuff i shouldnt click on or download. If i change my mind, ill use a standard account thanks again again again

Comment: ^ basically what Harry said @cheezguy. If you trust yourself and the system to do their respective jobs then there is little difference between the two ways on your own computers. If you download and run malware on a standard account then it can simply sit there waiting for its time to shine, same goes for an admin account with UAC.  It boils down to whether you trust yourself not to blindly click OK if the screen flashes black and asks for admin rights at that point. If it happens the only question is "do I expect it to ask for that?"

Comment: i see @Mokubai i know how dangerous giving admin rights to random programs is. I double check every link i click and follow basic internet safety. Even have uac on max. also use ublock and other antivirus extensions to block harmfull ads, scripts. Thank you both for helping me.

Comment: also @Mokubai what do you mean by the system? im a regular home computer user. i dont work for a organization or sumthn

Comment: The system as in the computer and operating system.